# npm dependency in cloud functions

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-functions

I've defined my [npm dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phash-image) in the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "phash-hamming",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "phash-image": "3.5.0"
  }
}
```

In my `index.js` the first line causes an error:

```
var phash = require('phash-image');
```

The Error:

> Build failed: exit status 1
>
> > phash-image@3.5.0 install /workspace/node_modules/phash-image
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found gyp: Call to 'pkg-config
>   --libs-only-L --libs-only-other pHash' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp gyp ERR! configure
>   error  gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
>   (/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-116-generic gyp ERR! command
>   "/nodejs/bin/node"
>   "/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/node_modules/phash-image gyp ERR!
>   node -v v6.11.5 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0 gyp ERR! not ok

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mgmtio/phash-image

Read the `Installation` section.

> phash-image depends on CImg, pHash, ImageMagicK.

Do you have install one of above?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1.Load the `phash-image` library from inside the function you are calling.

2.Use the package.json from the phash-image repo.

Your index.js:

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  var phash = require('phash-image');
};
```

Your package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "phash-image",
  "version": "3.5.0",
  "description": "phash for images",
  "repository": "mgmtio/phash-image",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.1.5",
    "hamming-distance": "^1.0.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.2",
    "mocha": "^3.0.0",
    "node-gyp": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "script": {
    "preinstall": "node-gyp configure build",
    "preuninstall": "rm -rf build/*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node-gyp configure build",
    "test": "npm run build && mocha",
    "test-cov": "npm run build && istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --reporter dot",
    "test-travis": "npm run build && istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --report lcovonly -- --reporter dot"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "pHash",
    "phash",
    "libpHash",
    "native",
    "binding",
    "addon"
  ],
  "author": "Aaron Marasco <agm257@mail.missouri.edu>",
  "contributors": [
    "Aaron Marasco <agm257@mail.missouri.edu>",
    "Taeho Kim <xissysnd@gmail.com>",
    "Jeremy Dowell <jeremy@codevinsky.com>",
    "Rod Vagg <r@va.gg> (https://github.com/rvagg)",
    "Jonathan Ong <me@jongleberry.com> (https://github.com/jonathanong)"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "any-promise": "^1.1.0",
    "nan": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```